# Table cells that activate other tables with Javascript by changing the z-index

Tags: javascript, html-table, cell, z-index

I have no idea how this isn't working. I've tried switching around the properties, putting divs inside each table cell and using that for the "click" function. But no matter what I do I just can't seem to get it working. All i need is just the table cell with the weblink info in it, to click and open up the secondary table using the z-index format to overlap them. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#weblinkbut').click(function(){
        $('.menuhome').css('z-index','3');
        $('.weblinkmenu').css('z-indez','4');
     });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="weblinkbut">
<p>content</p>
</div>

<div id="menuhome">
<table class="menuhome" width="181" height="208" border="1" 
     bordercolor="#000000" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="">
<tr>
<td width="75" height="90"><p>&nbsp;</p><p><img src="images/weblinkicon.png"   
     width="40" height="40"></p>
    <p>Website link</p></div></td>
    <td width="75" height="90"><p><img src="images/phoneicon.png" 
     width="40" height="40"></p>
    <p>Phone Number</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="75" height="90"><p><img src="images/emailicon.jpg" width="40"     
         height="40"></p>
    <p>Email address</p></td>
    <td width="75" height="90"><p><img src="images/newdocicon.png" width="30" 
     height="40">
    <P>Plain Text</P>    
</tr>
</table>
 </div>

 <div id="weblinkmenu">
<table class="weblinkmenu" width="181" height="208" border="1"    
     bordercolor="#000000" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="">
    <tr>
        <td width="75" height="90"><p><img src="images/weblinkicon.png" 
                width="40" height="40"></p>
            <p>Website link</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
 </div>

 </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DOM isn't fully loaded when you try to bind a handler for the click event.
Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#weblinkbut').click(function(){
    $('.menuhome').css('z-index','3');
    $('.weblinkmenu').css('z-indez','4');
  });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work. I've copy and pasted the script you sent into my doc and still nothing. I'm trying to use the table cell, with the weblink icon in it, so when i click on it i'll open up the weblinkmenu overlapping the menuhome with css style z-index.